# my win 2003 server hang when using robocopy to backup

Tags: windows

Whenever I run this backup script, it hanged
script:

```
robocopy C:\source D:\destination *.* /E /COPYALL /XO /PURGE /V /NP /LOG:"G:\WebBackupLog.txt"
```

It hanged and I cannot press any key. I can only use the power button to restart the computer

I read the log file and found that when it hanged when it is copying a mp3 file. 
Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you're not letting it run to completion? How long are you waiting?

Comment: Does the operating system freeze completely including the mouse cursor? Can you copy-paste that mp3 manually (right-click and copy/paste)?

Comment: I was going to blame Windows Dynamic Cache, but that's a 2008 and after enhancement.

Comment: Try copying the mp3 file manually and see what happens. Try moving the MP3 elsewhere and let the copy complete without it just to test to see what happens. Also, look into using the `R:5` and `W:5` switches so it doesn't retry the default 1 million times as that could be the issue as well if the file is not copying and it's retrying 1 million times with a 30 second delay between each retry.... Just a thought but perhaps it'll be a solution in your case, I'll be happy to add as an answer if you confirm.

Comment: I have tried copying the mp3 file manually without any problems. I have disabled the robocopy scheduled task to avoid hanging. There are still 10GB free in the destination drive

Comment: I have waited for several hrs and it keeped hanging. I can't used the mouse as it is completeley freezed. I am waiting for next long holiday so I can try editing the backup script